# AWSS3TransferUtility background upload - disable cellular access (wi-fi only)

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, background, awss3transferutility

Yo. I'm working with the AWS S3 SDK on iOS, and need to upload large files (videos).

Since they're large, I need the upload to continue while the app is in the background, suspended or terminated (`AWSS3TransferUtility` does the heavy lifting here).

Also, since they're large, I want to **pause uploads when not connected to WiFi**, and resume when reconnected. I believe this is the nature of an `NSURLSession` configured with `allowsCellularAccess = NO`.

Since I cannot, while the app is in background or terminated, watch reachability and manually pause/resume tasks, I expect this must be configured on the `AWSS3TransferUtility`, but alas have not found any means of doing so.

Does anyone know if this is possible, and how to achieve said goal?

Very much appreciated.

--

PS: 
Example code I'm working with is Amazon's example project: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/master/S3BackgroundTransfer-Sample

Obj-c, iOS 9

Comment: Currently, the SDK does not expose `AWSNSURLSessionConfiguration`. If you are using CocoaPods, you can modify the SDK code for yourself. A similar [feature request](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/issues/279) is open on the GitHub repo. You can ask for this as a feature request there as well.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now possible, as of [AWS SDK v2.3.6](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#236):

```
let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType: myRegion, identityPoolId: myIdentityPoolId)
let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: myRegion, credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)
configuration.allowsCellularAccess = false
AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration
```

Comment: is it still effective to change it while it is working?

Comment: @Dincer no I don't think so. I think you have to tear the whole thing down and reinstantiate. I haven't implemented that yet though.

Comment: Yes, that's how I went for. However if I'm not mistaken, URLSessionTask may resist to pause the ongoing task. You might have to wait for it to surrender. Then do the cellular thing and resume.